# RPC_ERROR when I migrate module from odoo15 to odoo16

Tags: python, odoo-15, odoo-16

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
at makeErrorFromResponse (http://134.122.110.222:10016/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10383:19) (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:34)
at XMLHttpRequest. (http://134.122.110.222:10016/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10436:27) (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:87)

Comment: please provide the url of the page and whole Error-Traceback (as we have no access on your url). And, open the console in your browser to click on the provided error-line-link...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.